# Replace accented characters except in Row 6

Tags: excel, vba, character

This code replaces all accented characters on a sheet:

```
Const sFm As String = "ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ"
Const sTo As String = "SZszYAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyy"

Dim i As Long, employeews As Worksheet

Set employeews = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

For i = 1 To Len(sFm)
    employeews.Cells.Replace Mid(sFm, i, 1), Mid(sTo, i, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True
Next i
```

I don't want to replace anything in Row 6, how do I do this?

Comment: Depending on your setup, read row 6 into an array, do the replace as you currently have it, and then write the array back to row 6.

Comment: @BigBen I'm a beginner on VBA, how exactly do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your setup, read row 6 into an array, do the replace as you currently have it, and then write the array back to row 6.

```
Dim rowSix() as Variant
rowSix = employeews.Rows(6).Value

For i = 1 To Len(sFm)
    employeews.Cells.Replace Mid(sFm, i, 1), Mid(sTo, i, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=True
Next i

employeews.Rows(6).Value = rowSix
```

Note that this will overwrite formulas in row 6, so if that's your setup you'll need a different approach.